# Identical files issue with Nginx and FastCG on separate servers

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

When using NGINX Plus with FastCGi ( PHP-FPM ), the issue is that we need to have identical set of files on both the Nginx Plus as well as FastCGI Servers.

Here is my sample configuration :-

Machine 1 : Nginx Plus
Machine 2 : FastCGI ( PHP-FPM )

My Nginx Configuration :

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  kp.in;
    root /var/example/;

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   172.16.38.179:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        ........ 
        ........
 }
```

I have a simple "hello.php" file in the /var/example/ ( Document Root ) in both NGINX as well as FastCGI Server. If i remove hello.php from NGINX Document Root, then in browser, Nginx says 404 Not found.

Is there any work around for this ? Ideally I want to keep all PHP file to FastCGi ( PHP-FPM ) server itself instead of keeping it in multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

A common implementation of `nginx` and `php-fpm` places both services on the same server within the same file system. And a common technique to avoid [passing uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) is to add a `try_files` directive to the PHP location block.

The purpose of `try_files` is to ensure that the file exists within the local file system before passing its name to the local PHP interpreter.

Where the interpreter is not local, other techniques should be employed to avoid sending malformed filenames to the upstream, such as `fastcgi_split_path_info`.

In your particular case, the `\.php$` regex does not accept pathinfo and is therefore not susceptible to the pathinfo exploit. Simply delete the `try_files $uri =404;` line from your `location ~ \.php$` container. *You can also lose the `fastcgi_index` as the container does not see bare directories either.*

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass  172.16.38.179:9000;
    ...
}
```